# Analytics data not logged any more after upgrading to Flurry 4.1.0 android sdk

Tags: android, analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

After upgrading flurry analytics sdk from v3.3.3 to 4.1.0 our Flurry dashboard went dead for the new version - not analytics traffic seems to be flowing in. 
As far as we could tell we did not change anything in our analytics code, so can't explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We filed a support ticket to Flurry, they were fast to answer and currently looking into this.

In the meanwhile, we have rolled back to SDK v3.3.3, and data is showing on the dashboard once again, so we *assume* the problem was a result of some kind of compatibility issue with the way we integrate to it, but can't tell what.